# How can weight of a keras model be re-initialized?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I've got a cross-validation function I use across many types of models (sklearn, XGBoost, LightGBM) and I'm trying to extend it to keras.

The problems seems to be that when I pass a keras model to the function, instead of restarting training at each fold, it uses previously learned weights. I've been searching left and right but failed to find a straightforward way of just re-initializing a keras' model weights to their random state.
Right now the workaround I'm using is to save the model's random weights before the first fold trains, and re-load them after each fold. It's kind of ugly and would rather avoid it.

The simplified function is:

```
def cvloopcv(X,y,model,n,**kwargs):

    kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n,
                shuffle=True,
                random_state=SEED)


    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):

        model.fit(X[train_index], y[train_index])

        if isinstance(model,Sequential):
            preds = model.predict_proba(X[test_index]).flatten()
        else:
            preds = model.predict_proba(X[test_index])[:,1]

        ...do a bunch of things here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile your model in your training loop.

> `for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
>           model.compile()`

This will recompile and reinitialize your model to some new random weights

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I train the model, do model.get_weights(), then model.compile() and again model.get_weights(), the weights I get the first (after training) and second time (after re-initializing) are the exact same.

Comment: In that case, if possible you can  try to instantiate the model as well in the training loop

Comment: @user263961 how does your model look like? What kind of `kernel_initializer` are u using? It is very unusual to initialize your weights randomly and that you have the same weights after the first and second training.

Comment: @CodePope I'm playing around with different architectures, just learning. But a pretty standard Sequential model with an embedding layer, a RNN layer and a binary output. I have not touched kernel_initializer.